# Using React with Bootstrap Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I want to use [bootstrap toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) inside a [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) component. However a regular checkbox is shown instead of a styled element. How that could be fixed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS --> <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        var WordCheckBox = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <div className="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="On" data-off="Off" />
                            option1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    );
            }
        });
        React.render(
            <WordCheckBox />,
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>

    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--doesn't work. checkbox instead of toogle shown-->
    <div id="content"> </div>
    <!--works-->
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="On" data-off="Off">
            <span>option2</span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <!--works-->
    <div class="checkbox" data-reactid=".0">
        <label data-reactid=".0.0">
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"
                   data-on="On" data-off="Off"
                   data-reactid=".0.0.0">
            <span data-reactid=".0.0.1">option3</span>
        </label>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using React Bootstrap: http://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: @David i can not toogle element there.

Comment: From looking at the demo, it looks like the code manipulates the DOM, which means it's not easily compatible with ReactJS as currently written.

Comment: @WiredPrairie that's sad. Can I specify order in with they will manipulate DOM or do some other smart thing?

Comment: No. If you look at @David's suggestion, you'll see that it generates HTML that exactly matches what Bootstrap would have done for a given component. It's not manipulated/morphed at run-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [their docs](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)

You need to wire up the plugin's functionality when your React component mounts (when it spits out the HTML into the DOM)

Add a `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook and give the input a `ref` attribute to accomplish this.

```
var WordCheckBox = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {

      $( this.refs.toggleInput.getDOMNode() ).bootstrapToggle();

    }

    ...

    render: function() {

        ...

        <input ref="toggleInput" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="On" data-off="Off" />
```

Comment: I've found this solution fails when attaching an event handler to the react component.  It seems `bootstrapToggle` manipulates the DOM enough to create its own checkbox that isn't tied to the react event system.  If I'm correct, then a complete solution may be a rewrite of bootstrap toggle as a reactjs component.  If you're only relying on form submissions, then this answer appears to work.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying the solution and I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapToggle is not a function`. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

If your input are added dynamically like it was the case for me, you'll want to call the function in the componentDidUpdate function.

Also, you'll then probably get the input by class instead of refs.

```
componentDidUpdate()
{
    $('.toggleInput').bootstrapToggle();
}
```

And further:

```
<input className="toggleInput" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

Answer (score 0):

on - Sets the toggle to 'On' state 
off - Sets the toggle to 'Off' state

```
componentDidMount: function() {

  $( this.refs.toggleInput.getDOMNode() ).bootstrapToggle('on');

}
```